# What causes an Android App to Timeout?

Tags: android, image, garbage-collection, timeout

What causes an Android App to timeout?  (I cannot believe nobody has asked this!)

I am assuming it is related to drawing and garbage collecting images.  With the problem below, how can we prevent this from causing a crash?  If specifics are desired, just ask.  Thanks!

```
08-12 16:59:42.640: D/dalvikvm(17719): GC_CONCURRENT freed 293K, 15% free 10256K/11968K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
08-12 16:59:42.710: D/dalvikvm(17719): GC_CONCURRENT freed 494K, 11% free 10746K/11968K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
08-12 16:59:43.270: D/dalvikvm(17719): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1272K, 13% free 10421K/11968K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
08-12 16:59:43.600: D/dalvikvm(17719): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1587K, 19% free 9770K/11968K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 25ms
08-12 16:59:43.600: D/dalvikvm(17719): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
08-12 16:59:49.200: I/dalvikvm(17719): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-12 16:59:49.220: I/dalvikvm(17719): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: "What causes an Android App to timeout?" -- please define "timeout".

Comment: Did you use a async task ? Read that: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: Just read up on that. thanks! an answer with that will get the checkmark